# Spring MVC Dependency Injection not working in object called from within RequestMappingController

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, controller

When I try to do like below and I have a RequestMapping controller class within Spring MVC that instantiates and calls an external class, I am unable to use dependency injection within that class, such as if I try to use

```
@Resource(name = "savedsearchesService")
        private SavedSearchesService savedsearchesService;
```

I get a nullpointer exception. Instead I have to pass `SavedSearchesService savedsearchesService` from my controller method into the other external method to get it to work.

I'm wondering if anyone can point out why it is this way as I am curious and if there is something I am missing as far as how to do this properly. Thanks

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class MainController {

    @Resource(name = "savedsearchesService")
    private SavedSearchesService savedsearchesService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersons(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        SomeExternalClass someExternalClass = new SomeExternalClass ();
        someExternalClass.Main();
    }

}
```

Here is the example of the external classs:

```
public class SomeExternalClass {

    @Resource(name = "savedsearchesService")
    private SavedSearchesService savedsearchesService;

    public void Main () {
        savedsearchesService.get();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
SomeExternalClass someExternalClass = new SomeExternalClass();
```

All classes which depends on springs dependency injection must be **spring managed**, which is not the case whenever you instantiate classes with the **new** keyword.

There are several alternatives. To mention some:

- Inject `SomeExternalClass` into your controller.
- Create a spring-managed factory which hides instantiation logic (such as `applicationContext.getBean()`)

Comment: oh ok that makes sense... thanks, I need to go back and review some of the basics :)